# "of their being" vs "of there being"

Tags: grammar

I am reading a BBC article on "[Why pressing ‘upload’ means losing your rights](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20131119-stop-do-not-press-upload)". On page 2 of that article there is a paragraph that reads:

*Meanwhile, legal thinking on digital rights is slowly catching up with the absurdity **of their being** almost no current recourse for loss, deletion or the whims of a service provider; but its pace is massively exceeded by the rate at which material is flowing online, into the hands of businesses whose profitability rests on owning and exploiting everything you give them.*

My question is what is the difference between "of their being" and "of there being", and are both acceptable and when? Both have millions of results on Google. I know ***their*** is used for possession but I don't understand how that fits in here.

Thank you

Comment: It's just sloppy editing. It happens frequently with *there/their/they're* and *your/you're*, even to the best of us. Homophones become hard to spot, especially by the author, because as you read it back to yourself, you don't hear a difference and often substitute the correct word for the incorrect one in your head without noticing. *Of their being* would reference someone's existence. *There* is the correct choice, which is why it didn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should definitely be "of there being" in the referenced paragraph.

Let us illustrate by providing possible alternative wordings:

1. A consequence of their being is ...
2. A consequence of their being available is ...
3. A consequence of there being a solution is ...

These can be rephrased as:

1. A consequence of their existence is ...
2. A consequence of their availability is ...
3. A consequence of the existence of a solution is ...

---

So what is going on?

- "Their being", and "their being *[adjective]*" refer to the existence, respectively the property expressed by the adjective, of the subject referenced by "their".
- "There being", on the other hand, indicates a general state of affairs.

I hope that clarifies the matter for you.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I agree that it's an error.

Possessive adjectives are used before gerunds *(My coming surprised everyone*) and not object pronouns (*Me coming surprised everyone*).

This latter is heard more and more and thus represents a change in progress.

But there is no possessive adjective for *there* and in the sentence, there is no logical reference for the *their*, so it seems to be an oversight in the editing.

Answer (score 0):

"... what is the difference between "of their being" and "of there being"..."

"Their being" relates to the question, "Whose being?"
"There being" introduces an explanation of something.  This is what the hurried BBC writer meant.  You could replace his "of their being" with "of the fact that".

This headline popped up on a Google search:  "There is not much hope of their being alive".

Answer (score 0):

All good answers. A good shortcut: in “of their being...”, simply replace “their” with “them” giving: “of them being...”, which, if it still makes sense (in colloquial English), means that “their” was correct.

Comment: Hi, can you give more context in your example as it relates to the question?  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Answer (score -1):

Which is the more correct?

1- No music can occur today, their being some dancing on a Saturday.

OR

2- No music can occur today, there being some dancing on a Saturday.

Confusing, but the second sentence is more accurate as the dancing is not possessive - i.e. not belonging to anyone and the use of "their" in this instance  is essentially incorrect in the 21st century.